# List or ObservableCollection?

Tags: wpf, xaml, observablecollection

Is there any difference in performance to use `ObservableCollection`, which (as I understand) refreshes view each time item added to collection, or instead use simple `List` collection, and refresh whole view when all elements already added?

And is the scenario with `List` as decried above even possible? How to implement this then?

I'm asking because my ItemsControl is slow, and I wonder if it would be better to use simple List instead ObservableCollection. I need to refresh the view only once at a time, when actually all elements already added to collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IList<T>` just as `List<T>` does. The main difference is of course, that it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which allows WPF to bind to it.

The `ObservableCollection<T>` throws an event after each change so the UI can Refresh. If you are adding a lot of Items sequentially, it can have some impact to your performance but that is unlikely. You can test this rather simple by using the Constructor which takes a List:

```
var originalList = new List<SomeClass>();

foreach ([..])
{
  originalList.Add(someInstance);
}

ObservableCollection<SomeClass> uiCollection = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>(originalList);
```

This way you can create you complex List of objects and after its finished you can create an ObservableCollection out of it which you will Bind to on the UI.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't plan to add or remove items dynamically at runtime, you might as well use a `List<T>` instead of an `ObservableCollection<T>`. The difference in performance will be negligible though.

The special thing about the `ObservableCollection<T>` is that it implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

WPF subscribes to the `CollectionChanged` event of any collection that implements this interface to listen for collection changes. So if you for some reason want to create your own custom collection that supports change notifications, you could create a class that implements this interface.

I strongly doubt that your performance issues is related to the type of source collection you are using though. You should make sure that UI virtualization is enabled and go trough the following list of suggestions on how to improve the performance of Controls in WPF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx